# Add HTML code triggered by selection changed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple select into my HTML code (a dropdown menu).

HTML

```
<select name="razza" onchange="razzaChanged()">
      <?php while ($row = gdrcd_query($result, 'fetch')){ ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $row['id_razza']; ?>" <?php if(gdrcd_filter('get',$_POST['razza'])==$row['id_razza']){ echo 'SELECTED'; } ?>>
           <?php echo gdrcd_filter('out',$row['nome_razza']); ?>
         </option>
      <?php } ?>
```

JavaScript

```
   <script>
    function razzaChanged()
    {
       alert("I am an alert box!");
    }
   </script>
```

When the selection of the dropdown is chosen, I have to add some information below the dropdown. The information I have to add is a bit complex and pretty formatted (I need to do some query to retrieve data and then add text and another dropdown after the info).

How can I achieve this? I can register via JavaScript that the selection changed but then I don't know how to go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ajax methods. Get value from select using oninput/onchange, use that value as data in ajax request. If request is successful then show server's response in a container where ever you want.

## HTML

```
<select name="razza" id="razza">
<option value="1">Some Option</option>
<option value="2">Another Option</option>
<!-- Use your loop here and remove these options -->
</select>
```

## Javascript

```
$("#razza").on('input change',function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  // Ajax Request
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post', // you can also use 'get'
    url: '/link/to/your/server/file',
    data: {
     key: value // use key required by backend
    },
    success: function(response) {
         $('#your-container-div-id').html(response);
    }
  });
});
```

Please note that I have used code without 'onchange' attribute, as this is better. Feel free to ask...

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do an `AJAX` `POST` or `GET` request to retrieve data from your database and you will need to use `document.createElement("elementtype");` to create an element to add to your page.

With jQuery, your `AJAX` would look something like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
type: "POST",//can be GET or POST
url: "yoururl",
statusCode: {
404: function() {
  alert( "page not found" );
},
data: {key: value},//you can have multiple keys and values
success: function(res){
    //add elements to the page
    $('#yourelememntid').html(res.someattribute);
}
}).done(function() {
//AJAX request finished
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to achieve this. One would be to use what jquery library offers.

Here are just some very rough steps of how one could do it:

In your razzaChanged() function establish which value is selected:

```
function razzaChanged()
{
     var val = $('select[name="razza"] option:selected').val();
     // step 2 here
}
```

Now use this value to fetch data from the server with the help of AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/your-url-to-call',
    data: 'your_value=' + val,
    success: function(data) {
        // step 3 here
    }
});
```

Now having data from server (i.e. json format) build your new select dropdown, i.e.:

```
var newSelect = $('<select>').appendTo('body');
$(data).each(function() {
    newSelect.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.some_property).text(this.some_text));
});
```

It's definitely not a ready-to-use code as you would have to make sure you return properly formatted data on server side or change the code accordingly. Also 
make sure jquery library is loaded and the code is wrapped with its ready function (easy to find example on internet).
Hope this helps.